# How to open new window with out changing current URL?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I am trying to open a new window from jquery and the problem that it changes the current window url and target url. I need to change only target url. What I did wrong?

```
var number = $('#number').text().substring(1, $('#number').text().length);

history.pushState(null, null, '/somepage/' + number + '/details');

window.open(
    window.location.href,
    '_blank'
);
```

Is it possible to change only target url, but current url leave the same?

Comment: *I am trying to open a new window from jquery* Not really. You just use jquery to generate a string.

Comment: Why are you using pushState() if you don't want to change current url? Please explain in more detail what you need to accomplish with regard to both windows. See [ask]

Comment: charlietfl, I try to open new window with new url and current leave the same. I do not have any idea.

Comment: Then don't use pushState() and just create the new url as a string to pass to `window.open(newUrlString)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`history.pushState` changes the current windows's URL. You are then opening a new window at the same location.

You want to skip the pushState and pass the URL straight to `window.open`.

```
var number = $('#number').text().substring(1, $('#number').text().length);

window.open(
    '/somepage/' + number + '/details',
    '_blank'
);
```